# Late type in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm working with two crates: A and B. I control both. I'd like to create a struct in A that has a field whose type is known only to B (i.e., A is independent of B, but B is dependent on A).

`crate_a:`

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Thing {
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: *const i32,
}

impl Thing {
    fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Thing { foo: x, bar: &0 }
    }
}
```

`crate_b:`

```rust
struct Value {};

fn func1() {
    let mut x = A::Thing::new(1);
    let y = Value {};
    x.bar = &y as *const Value as *const i32;
    ...
}

fn func2() {
    ...
    let y = unsafe { &*(x.bar as *const Value) };
    ...
}
```

This works, but it doesn't feel very "rusty". Is there a cleaner way to do this? I thought about using a trait object, but ran into issues with `Clone`.

Note: My reason for splitting these out is that the dependencies in B make compilation very slow. `Value` above is actually from llvm_sys. I'd rather not leak that into A, which has no other dependency on llvm.

Comment: can you use generics?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'd want to either make `Thing` generic over the dependent's type or use `Box<dyn Any>` (or similar) (though yeah, you'll have troubles with `Clone` then)

Comment: @Stargateur Whether accessing a freed ZST is UB [is actually a matter of discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/93).

Comment: Is `Box<dyn Any>` with downcasts acceptable?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 1 real code of OP is 102% not ZST, 2 by default until the contrary is decided it's UB 3 it's really don't look good, what is the alignment of a ZST type ? that look SO wrong. For all theses reason I maintain my claim :p

Comment: @Stargateur Why does alignment matter? Anyway, I agree this code looks bad, but IMO until this is decided this is not UB but should (must?) be avoided.

Comment: I'm not sure if `&0` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to implement something like this is with [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html), which are kind of like type variables: they can be "assigned" a particular type, possibly within some constraints.  This is how the standard library can provide types like [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) that work with types that you declare in your crate.

Basically, generics allow `Thing` to be defined in terms of "some unknown type that will become known later when this type is actually used."

Given the example in your code, it looks like `Thing`'s `bar` field may or may not be set, which suggests that the built-in [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) enum should be used.  All you have to do is put a type parameter on `Thing` and pass that through to `Option`, like so:

```
pub mod A {
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct Thing<T> {
        pub foo: i32,
        pub bar: Option<T>,
    }
    
    impl<T> Thing<T> {
        pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
            Thing { foo: x, bar: None }
        }
    }
}

pub mod B {
    use crate::A;
    
    struct Value;
    
    fn func1() {
        let mut x = A::Thing::new(1);
        let y = Value;
        x.bar = Some(y);
        // ...
    }
    
    fn func2(x: &A::Thing<Value>) {
        // ...
        let y: &Value = x.bar.as_ref().unwrap();
        // ...
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=810a99804b697600b667565579bbeafe))

Here, the `x` in `B::func1()` has the type `Thing<Value>`.  You can see with this syntax how `Value` is substituted for `T`, which makes the `bar` field `Option<Value>`.

If `Thing`'s `bar` isn't actually supposed to be optional, just write `pub bar: T` instead, and accept a `T` in `Thing::new()` to initialize it:

```
pub mod A {
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct Thing<T> {
        pub foo: i32,
        pub bar: T,
    }
    
    impl<T> Thing<T> {
        pub fn new(x: i32, y: T) -> Self {
            Thing { foo: x, bar: y }
        }
    }
}

pub mod B {
    use crate::A;
    
    struct Value;
    
    fn func1() {
        let mut x = A::Thing::new(1, Value);
        // ...
    }
    
    fn func2(x: &A::Thing<Value>) {
        // ...
        let y: &Value = &x.bar;
        // ...
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71477e69bb007b1f84e265f37b6eb12f))

Note that the definition of `Thing` in both of these cases doesn't actually require that `T` implement `Clone`; however, `Thing<T>` will only implement `Clone` if `T` also does.  `#[derive(Clone)]` will generate an implementation like:

```
impl<T> Clone for Thing<T> where T: Clone { /* ... */ }
```

This can allow your type to be more flexible -- it can now be used in contexts that don't require `T` to implement `Clone`, while also being cloneable when `T` does implement `Clone`.  You get the best of both worlds this way.

Comment: Or, require `impl<T> Thing<T> where T: Default` for `new(x)` without `Option`.

Comment: @Finomnis Sure, or just `#[derive(Default)]`. There's a few ways to handle construction -- even the builder pattern, for example, but I wanted to make the code in my answer match the code in the question as much as possible to help OP see the transformation to generics without muddying the water with other stuff.